# setInterval working termination undefined

Tags: javascript, express, request, fetch, setinterval

take a look at my code. 
My "setInterval" sends no more than 10 requests.
And it stops working. And it always gets a response from the server.
Why does this happen and how can I fight it? I tried using axios the same problem.

```
setInterval(function() {
console.log('i'm here')
    fetch(`/api/....`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log('I'm here')
        console.log(res)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}, 1000);
```

Sometimes such an error also flies by:`TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

Comment: Nothing to do with your particular problem, but FYI, it is pointless to send `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` with a GET request.  The `Content-Type` applies to the content of the body you are sending with the request (not what you are hoping to get back as a response) and since there is no body with a GET request, it is pointless to set the `Content-Type` header at all on a GET request.  The `Accept` headers tells the server what type of response you would like to get back.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oops. I wrote that by hand. Corrected the question. (I have POST).

Comment: Now you're showing a POST with no body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your backend co-operates there is no reason why your JavaScript code should not work:

```js
var i=0,
iv=setInterval(function() {
console.log(`I'm here: ${++i}`);
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 body: JSON.stringify({newId:i})
}).then(r=>r.json()).then(res=>{
    console.log(`I'm back: ${res.newId}`);
    console.log(res);
    if(i==25) clearInterval(iv);
}).catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
}, 1000);
```

(There were a few typos in your `console.log`s which I straightened out.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to said without the server side's codes, but I can guess there is some limitation in your express application which limit the numbers of your requsts to 10.
It is nothing to do with you javascript code which sould fire without any problem more then 10 requests.
As you can see in this article [Rate Limiting](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/nodejs-rate-limiting/),

```
const express = require("express");
const indexRoute = require("./router");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(
  rateLimit({
    windowMs: 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 12 hour duration in milliseconds
    max: 5,
    message: "You exceeded 100 requests in 12 hour limit!",
    headers: true,
  })
);
```

You can limit the available requests by changing the `max` value.